# Dialogue window for ground to grid tool in arcmap 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, tools

I am using ground to grid correction tool with some success but in the window I cannot see all the print.

Is there a way to size the window? Does anyone know how to apply ground to grid correction ?
For this is self taught and I see the results but not sure if the workflow I am using is the best approach.

I am using Arcmap 10 on a network.

Answer (score 1):

If you are following the [help from esri](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m70000005w000000)
The only suggestion I have is to change the reference scale.
Right click on the data frame in the TOC and choose properties.
[image: properties]

On the General tab change the reference scale to something larger.
which should make the text get smaller.

[image: refscale]